# VB.Net WinForms Reference Combobox SelectedValue using ActiveForms.Controls

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I'm attempting to get the SelectedValue of a **combobox** without specifying the form name by using ActiveForm. Its being used in a Query thats located in a class file and can be used from two different forms so it needs to be generic.

```
Dim AcctDetailsAdapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Accounts] WHERE_
[AcctName] = '" & Form.ActiveForm.Controls("SelectAccount").SelectedValue & "'", db.connect)
```

The section below is where it breaks obviously, and I cant come up with another way around it.

```
Form.ActiveForm.Controls("SelectAccount").SelectedValue
```

I can use this when referencing textboxes with no issue, but in my query where I need to use "selectedvalue" I'm not able to come up with a solution. Any ideas or any alternate directions I'm not thinking of? I'm extremely new to vb.net.

I also tried using a variable to capture the ActiveForm Name in order to pass it along, but that didnt seem to work either.

UPDATE: I've been able to get this to work correctly with Jimi's assistance using the code below:

```
Dim SelectedAccount = TryCast(Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("SelectAccount", True).FirstOrDefault, ComboBox).SelectedValue.ToString()
Dim AcctDetailsAdapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM [Accounts] WHERE [AcctName] = '{SelectedAccount}'", db.connect)
```

This hopefully helps with the passing parameters to the query referenced by the @jmcilhinney.

I have one last question now using this same principal, it does not appear to work for a ToolStripStatusLabel because it technically is not a control?

```
TryCast(Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("StatusLabel", True).FirstOrDefault, ToolStripStatusLabel).Text = "test"
```

Comment: `Dim comboValue = DirectCast(Form.ActiveForm.Controls("SelectAccount"), ComboBox).SelectedValue.ToString()`. You need 1) to be sure that `SelectAccount` is a control on that Form, otherwise you'll have a `NullReferenceException` (so, maybe get the Control reference first then try to extract a value), 2) You need to have set the `ComboBox.ValueMember` to get its `SelectedValue`. Use `ToString()` to convert it to a string. Setting `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit On` helps a lot.

Comment: Hi Jimi, I attempted your solution and I ran into the same issue as stated in the answer below. **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** I'm assuming it cant find any value from my combobox and its breaking, but 100% for sure I have a combobox by that name with values in it already. I know I'm missing something super basic somewhere.

Comment: You need to check what is the null reference. Is it the ComboBox reference you get back or the `Form.ActiveForm` object? Is you ComboBox control direct child of a Form or is it, maybe, child of another container (a Panel/SplitContainer/FlowLayoutPanel etc.). In this case, you can use the `Form.Controls.Find()` method, where you specify to search all child controls. When you have an exception, you need to specify the details of this exception. If you modified your code, update your question otherwise answers may become useless.

Comment: that was it!!! It was inside of a panel on my form! I didnt realize that that would come into play. I pulled it out of the panel and straight to the form and it worked perfect.

Comment: How would I go about adding the find into my scenario or referencing the panel.combobox? `Dim SelectedAccount = TryCast(Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("SelectAccount", True), ComboBox).SelectedValue.ToString()` Didnt seem to like me very much.

Comment: `Controls.Find()` returns a collection, not a single object. Get the first object found or null (`nothing`) if none is found:  `Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("SelectAccount", True).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you soooo much for your guidance. I'm also fairly new to Stackoverflow, how can I mark your answer as correct? Or give credit to you without just adding it to my original question?

Comment: Notify @jmcilhinney of the current scenario. Your code should look like: `Dim myCombo = TryCast(Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("SelectAccount", True).FirstOrDefault(), ComboBox) Dim selectedAccountValue as string = myCombo?.SelectedValue?.ToString()`, in my view. But maybe jmcilhinney has something else to suggest.

Answer (score -1):

When you index the `Controls` collection, you get back a `Control` reference.  Presumably, you are using the `Text` property for a `TextBox`.  `Text` is a member of the `Control` class, so you can use it for any control.  `SelectedValue` is a member of the `ComboBox` class, hence you have to cast as that type to access that member.  If you want to be safe, you ought to confirm there is such a control, e.g.

```
Dim cb = TryCast(Form.ActiveForm.Controls("SelectAccount"), ComboBox)

If cb IsNot Nothing Then
    'There is a ComboBox with that name on the active form, so use 'cb' here.
    Dim AcctDetailsAdapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM [Accounts] WHERE [AcctName] = '{cb.SelectedValue}'", db.connect)
```

You really ought to be using parameters to insert values into SQL code rather than string concatenation of any sort.  Even if you're safe from SQL injection, there is still the possibility of format errors or unpaired single quotes, e.g. your query will fail if the value is "O'Brien".  If you just use parameters every time then you can't go wrong.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this unfortunately - I understand the idea of trycast and getting to the combobox selected value, but I'm still pulling up with _"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"_. I've tested to make sure the correct "ActiveForm" by using **ActiveForm.Name** to display whats active, and it is. And 100% I have a combobox with values in place with the correct names.

Comment: Is it because my combobox is populated with a datasource? I just did a sandboxed test with your setup and it works perfectly fine if I manually load data into the combobox on Load.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney, I was able to use a combination of your parameters and Jimi's assistance above on "finding" a control in a panel. I've updated my original post above to include what I currently have in place and it seems to be working properly.